# Как правильно создать контрол WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как правильно создать свой контрол на основе стандартного radiobutton?
Попробовал создать класс, наследующий от radiobutton :

```
public partial class radioTest2:RadioButton{
    public string note;
    public radioTest2()
    {

    }
}
```

Но XAML его не видит, хотя :

```
xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:projectWPF2.rcontrols;
```

добавлен (контрол в отдельном NameSpace лежит).

Соответственно, код :

```
<MyNamespace:radioTest2></MyNamespace:radioTest2>
```

Выводит ошибку :

> "The name radioTest2 does not exist in namespace projectWPF2.rcontrols"

Что делать с этим, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Пробовал также создавать через UserControl (появляется еще xaml файл), но проблема осталась та же самая.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы что-то делаете не так. Вот мой код:

```csharp
// RadioTest2.cs
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SO8.RControls
{
    public class RadioTest2 : RadioButton
    {
    }
}

// RadioTest1.xaml.cs
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SO8.RControls
{
    public partial class RadioTest1 : UserControl
    {
        public RadioTest1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

```xaml
<!-- RadioTest1.xaml -->
<UserControl x:Class="SO8.RControls.RadioTest1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid/>
</UserControl>

<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->
<Window x:Class="SO8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MyNamespace="clr-namespace:SO8.RControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <MyNamespace:RadioTest2/>
        <MyNamespace:RadioTest1/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Код компилируется и запускается.

---

Мелочи по поводу вашего кода:

1. `public string note;` скорее всего неправильно, для использования в WPF вам нужно dependency property или по крайней мере property.
2. Скорее всего вам нужен `UserControl`, вряд ли то, что вы создаёте, является *разновидностью* `RadioButton`'а.
3. Namespace'ы и классы в C# принято именовать с большой буквы.

Comment: Проблема решилась перезапуском VS.